# Time Complexity of the following Code that uses 3 nested loops

Tags: c++, algorithm, time, time-complexity

Can someone please explain the proper time Complexity of this code below.

```
int sum,i,j,k,n;
sum = 0;
cin>>n;
int arr * = new int[n];
for (i=1;i<n;i=i*2){
   cin>>arr[i];
   for (j=0;j<n;++j)
       for (k=1;k<=n;k=k*2)
           sum+=arr[j];
}
```

Comment: No, no it is not.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay I disagree, because the `i` and `k` loops look to be `O(lgN)` to me.

Comment: The code has undefined behavior. The array isn't initialized so `arr[j]` accesses uninitialized values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounds of the three `for` loops do not appear to have any interdependencies.  So, we should be able to figure out the overall running time by just multiplying together the complexities of the three loops.

The loops in `i` and `k` are `O(lgN)`, because they double the loop counter at each iteration.  The middle loop in `j` is `O(N)`.  This yields `O(N*lgN*lgN)` as the overall complexity.

Comment: i think i got that. Thanks